# Erase only one element of a string(C++)

Tags: c++, string, erase

I have a string = "abcdefg". I will copy it to another string inside a loop. Then I want to erase only one character every time. First I will remove the character a from the first and it will be "bcdefg". Second time I will remove b and the string will be "acdefg". And so on. I tried to do it using erase() but it didn't work. You may take a look at how I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string abc = "abcdefg"; // the main string
    int len = abc.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        string cba = abc;       // I copy it to another string
        cba.erase(i,i+1);       // I try to erase only one element
        cout<<cba<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
bcdefg
acdefg
abdefg
abcefg
abcdfg
abcdeg
abcdef
```

But my code prints:

```
bcdefg
adefg
abfg
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
```

Can anybody please suggest me a way to do it correctly?? I'm really in danger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`std::basic_string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) function you are calling takes an **index** and a **count**. The second parameter is the number of characters to remove and you should be using `1`.

Answer (score 0):

For some example code:

```
//M a r k
//0 1 2 3
string name = "Mark"; 
//erase the single character 'r' at position 2
name.erase(2, 1); //M a k
```